# controllling the audio through keyboard

Tags: javascript, audio

I am able to control the audio through mouse is there any to control the audio through keyboard the code that i tried is here the controlling happens with button i need this without button how can i do this

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

    function playVid() { 
        vid.play(); 
    } 

    function pauseVid() { 
        vid.pause(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use postMessage, to transfer the data from one page to another. On the newly opened page do sth like this:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function(key){
 window.postMessage(key,"*");
});
```

To receive this, simply listen for the message event on your main site:

```
window.addEventListener("message",function(data){
origin=data.origin
//check if this is your site to prevent hijacking
key=data.data;
//do whatever
});
```

Comment: @xyz : nope. This is not a codewriting service :) . learn it yourself... My code will help you much

Comment: @xyz: ready comment ( /\ ) again. You should also read more about the "javascript sandbox"